# Can't make Xdebug work with Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I installed Visual Code on my UBUNTU a few days ago.
Every extentensions work well but Xdebug no (https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug).

I created the file "/home/sitesphp/wwwarchive22072017/testxdebug.php"  :

```
<?php
$a[] = 1;
var_dump($a);
?>
```

In Visual Studio, I supposed that when I click on DEBUG > Launch currently open script, variables will be described/displayed. Isn't it ?
On my side, nothing is displaying.

Here is my setup :

In a .php file with `phpinfo();` I've got this result :

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.8.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans

Then I suppose xDebug was well installed (cf. https://xdebug.org/docs/install)

My launch.json :

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
  {
   "name": "Listen for XDebug",
   "type": "php",
   "request": "launch",
   "port": 9000,
   "pathMappings": {
   "/home/sitesphp/wwwarchive22072017/": "${workspaceFolder}"
   }
  },
  {
   "name": "Launch currently open script",
   "type": "php",
   "request": "launch",
   "program": "${file}",
   "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
   "port": 3000
  }
 ]
}
```

I get "/home/sitesphp/wwwarchive22072017/" in my phpinfo(); > $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Maybe, it's the problem ?

My settings.json :

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath" : "/usr/bin/php",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
    "editor.tabSize": 1,
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "editor.minimap.showSlider": "always",
}
```

THX for your help

Comment: No comment ? No idea ?

Comment: Enable and collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session, it will tell where it tries to connect if it tries that at all. Once you have that info you can proceed further with those clues.